What is the meaning of the brown flower in Condé's "The Gospel According to the New World"?
The central character of The Gospel According to the New World is Pascal, who may (or may not) be the son of God. At his christening, his foster mother, Eulalie, is given a flower by a visitor (who may be an angel, Pascal's uncle, or the Holy Spirit, or indeed something entirely different). The flower has an "amazing color", namely:

light brown, the color of a light-skinned Capresse, with curly
velvet-like petals, wrapped around a delicate sulfur-yellow pistil.
“What a lovely flower! Eulalie exclaimed. “What a strange color!”
“This flower’s name is Tété Négresse,” the new arrival explained. “It
is designed to erase the Song of Solomon from our memory. You recall
those shocking words: I am Black but I am beautiful. These words must
never be pronounced again.”

 Part One, Chapter 3 
The Song of Solomon is a Biblical poem that indeed begins "I am black but I am beautiful" (or in some translations of the Bible "I am black, and I am beautiful").
Skin color is a recurrent theme in the book. Here, for example, the flower is called a "Negro's head", and its color is referred to as being like a "light-skinned Capresse" - a Capresse being a woman of mixed African and European ancestry. What is the purpose of giving the flower? Why will it erase the notion of "I am black but I am beautiful", and why would this be a desirable outcome?

This Le Monde article says:  Sep 4, 2021 — L'écrivaine antillaise poursuit son œuvre par une réécriture de la Bible transplantée en Guadeloupe, « L'Evangile du nouveau monde ». The West Indian author continues her literary work by a rewriting of the Bible transplanted to Guadeloupe. I look forward to reading the book. Just a minor point: it's really a Black woman's head.

@Lambie: Tête Négresse is the name of a rose. Do you translate the names of roses? Apparently not in the real world; there's Clair Matin, Bordure Nacrée, Étoile de Hollande, Frühlingsmorgen, Grande Siècle, La Sevillana and so on.

In the novel, the French text reads I am black but I am beautiful. I don't know whether the flower is designed to replace the but by and, or to erase the idea that something can be both black and beautiful.

The OP said: "Here, for example, the flower is called a "Negro's head", That is incorrect. It means: the head of a Black woman. Who says I'm translating it? I'm just re-explaining it correctly.

@PeterShor It seems that there is some disagreement between translators of the Bible whether to say "black but beautiful" or "black and beautiful". See this question for example: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/12922/black-but-beautiful-or-black-and-beautiful-in-song-of-songs

@ClaraDíazSanchez: The French Bible has been translated both ways, as well.

What Maryse Condé is offering us looks like a parody of the Annunciation, especially the version in the Gospel of Luke, chapter 1.
In the first chapter, Pascal's biological mother Maya repeatedly dreamt of an angel dressed in a blue tunic bringing her a "un lys de l'espèce  que l'on appelle 'lys canna'" ("a lily of the species called "canna lily'". In traditional Christian iconography, there is often a white lily, either in the angel's hands or in a vase standing somewhere [Feuillet]. However, the "canna lily" (lys canna), also known as Canna indica is neither a lily nor white. In addition, in Christian iconography, blue is a colour associated with the Virgin Mary ("Dans l’art religieux, la Vierge est presque toujours représentée avec un manteau bleu." Morard.) In Condé's description, however, it is the angel who is wearing blue. On top of this, he looks old, which stands in contrast with the young-looking angels in Christian iconography. (For an example of a painting that combines Mary's blue piece of clothing, the youthful angel Gabriel and the lily, see Leonardo's Annunciation.)
The inversion of the New Testament annunciation continues later in the chapter. For example, Déméter and his two acolytes are a parody of the Magi, and Pascal is born on Easter Sunday, the day of Jesus's death. The name 'Pascal' itself refers to the French adjective related to Easter (Pâques in French).
The visitor who appears at Pascal's christening is dressed in an equally old-fashioned way as the angel that Maya saw; he wears the same old-fashioned type of boots, has a greying beard (Maya's angel had grey hair) and appears to have a hunchback (i.e. where his clothing might cover an angel's wings).
The visitor addresses Eulalie with the following words:

Je vous salue, Eulalie, pleine de grâce, déclara-t-il, j'apporte un cadeau pour l'enfant Pascal.

Translation:

I greet you, Eulalie, full of grace, he declared, I bring a gift for the child Pascal.

First a few comments on the wording. The literal words are borrowed from Luke 1, 28. The first part is also close to the French version of the Hail Mary, which begins with the words, "Je vous salue Marie, pleine de grâce". Finally, "l'enfant Pascal" sounds just like "l'enfant pascal", bringing back the reference to Easter but also alluding to the agneau pascal / the Paschal lamb.
Second, there is the timing. The Biblical Annunciation takes place before the virgin birth of Jesus, whereas Eulalie's visitor appears after Pascal's birth, so the timing is inverted.
Third, the concept of virginity is stood on its head, both due to the timing of the visit and the fact that Eulalie and her husband did their best to conceive children but failed. Whereas the virgin birth of Jesus happens without the needed fertilisation, the fertilisation fails in the case of Eulalie and Jean-Pierre. In spite of this, Eulalie is not a virgin.
Finally, there is the flower gifted by the visitor. Whereas Annunciation scenes in paintings contain a white lily, the flower here is called a "rose Tété Négresse". Whereas the white lily is associated with virginity, the rose has many meanings in Western culture, mainly depending on its colour. Wikipedia enumerates several of these:

Examples of common meanings of different coloured roses are: true love (red), mystery (blue), innocence or purity (white), death (black), friendship (yellow), and passion (orange).

The "strange colour" of the rose offered to Pascal doesn't fit any traditional meaning. (Even the rose is connected with the Virgin Mary; the term rosary is also derived from it.)
The flower's name, Tété Négresse, is kind of double entendre. Both the OP and one of the comments interpret the name as referring to a head, i.e. a black woman's head. Interestingly, there is a kind of jewel called "tête négresse" that is popular in Guadeloupe; it is a kind of a golden ring inside which a series of small flowers are positioned on top of each other. However, the spelling of the flower's name is not "tête" (head) but "tété", a colloquial world for "breast" that is probably a cognate of "titty". It looks like Pascal gets a gift from a hunchback or decrepit angel in disguise whose name is almost a vulgar joke.
Finally, the visitor describes the flower as follows:

elle est destinée à faire oublier le Cantique des cantiques. Vous vous rappelez ces propos choquants : "Je suis noire mais je suis belle." De telles paroles ne doivent plus être prononcées.

Translation:

[the flower] is intended to make [people] forget the Song of Songs. You remember those shocking words: "I am black but I am beautiful." Such words must no longer be uttered.

The words "I am black but I am beautiful" (from Song of Solomon 1,5) stand in contrast to Black is beautiful, the name of a cultural movement that started in the United States in the 1960s. The "but" implies a contrast, as if black and beautiful were mutually exclusive. However, it has been pointed out, for example by Léopold Sédar Senghor, that this "but" is not correct:

Qu'on se souvienne seulement (…) de la reine de Saba, lançant aux
filles de Jérusalem : « Je suis noire, et je suis belle », ce qui est la
traduction mot à mot du texte et non pas : « Je suis noire, mais je
suis belle. »

Translation:

Let us only remember (…) the Queen of Sheba, saying to the daughters of Jerusalem: "I am black, and I am beautiful", which is the word-for-word translation of the text and not: "I am black, but I am beautiful."

What Senghor was referring to by "the word-for-word translation" is the fact that the Latin text on which the familiar translation is based ("Nigra sum sed formosa") distorts the Hebrew original. Liana Nissim tells us (page 329):

la traduction latine sed formosa est une entorse de l'hébreu qui, comme l'écrit Claire Pascal, "n'opère qu'une coordination", étant donné que "la particule we-, extrêmement fréquente dans la Bible […] peut avoir — selon Dominique Millet-Gérard — tantôt un sens de très légère liaison, tantôt uns sens très légèrement adversattif; son rôle est plutôt de soutenir les paralléllisme constants dans la poésie biblique". Aussie, Henri Meschonnic, dans sa traduction du Chant des Chants de 1970, choisit-il "Noire je suis et belle à voir", en assurant qu'il s'agit de "ce que dit exactement l'hébreu".

Translation:

the Latin translation sed formosa is a distortion of the Hebrew which, as Claire Pascal writes, "only operates a coordination", given that "the particle we-, extremely frequent in the Bible […] can have — according to Dominique Millet-Gérard — sometimes a sense of very slight connection, sometimes a very slightly adversative sense; its role is rather to support the constant parallelisms in biblical poetry". Also, Henri Meschonnic, in his 1970 translation of the Song of Songs, chooses "Black I am and beautiful to see", assuring that it is "exactly what the Hebrew says".

In other words, the contrast in "black but beautiful" should not be heard again because the implicit racism but also because it is in inaccurate translation.

Sources

Feuillet, Michel: Le jardin de l’Annonciation, Italies, 8 | 2004.
Morard, Anne Victoire: Comment interpréter la couleur bleue dans l’art chrétien ?, Aleteia, 15.08.2017.
Nissim, Liana: "'Moi je chante, comme le roi blond Salomon'. Le Cantique des cantiques selon Sengho", in: Le Cantique des Cantiques dans les Lettres Françaises. Convegno internazionale di Studi (Gargnano, 24-27 Giugno 2015). Led Edizioni Universitarie di Lettere Economia Diritto, 2016.
Senghor, Léopold Sédar: "Les Noirs dans l’Antiquité méditerranéenne" (PDF), Éthiopiques, 1977.


Thank you for the nice answer. Concentrating on the rose "erasing" the Song of Solomon, you think that as an object which is black and beautiful, it corrects the "black but beautiful" mis-translation? The rose is described as brown though, "the color of a light-skinned capresse" - might it not be correcting the SoS to "brown but beautiful" (or for that matter, "brown and beautiful")?

@ClaraDíazSanchez The colour of that flower sounds extremely specific and neither white nor black (since black roses and even black lilies exist). But the combination of the description of the flower and the visitor's comment on Song of Solomon might suggest together that it is not just black that is beautiful but also other non-white (skin) colours. (...)

The colour in the relevant phrase from Song of Solomon is not always translated as "black"; the most common alternative is "dark"; one translation even says "deeply tanned". But "black but beautiful" seems to be the most common pattern, so I think that's what the text seems to correct.

It's interesting that Condé uses the image of a black flower again in Segu: "With all his skill, and despite his bold experiments in crossbreeding, he'd never produced any black flowers. It was as if the color wasn't right; as if Nature didn't want anything to do with it."

@ClaraDíazSanchez I thought I had mentioned in my answer that black flowers (or at least flowers that are dark enough to be described as black) actually exist, but I forgot. See e.g. black roses and black tulips.

Yes, you mentioned it in a comment. But it seems that Condé (or one of he characters anyway) believes black flowers are impossible.
